# Can "harder" be used when the base case is null?

Tags: adverbs, comparatives

I'm mostly concerned with being able to say "I should try harder" when I'm currently not trying at all.

This seems right to me, but other similar situations like "I should jump higher" if I'm not jumping seem incorrect.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but unfortunately it's off-topic here because its not about English but rather the philosophy of language. You might try it on http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ if you make clear it's a question about language philosophy.

Comment: No, it's clearly about English, at least as much as such silliness as "Third Conditional" and their ilk. The question is whether there always has to be a _than_ clause in order to use a comparative. And the answer is no. Some baseline comparison will be assumed, starting in this case with _than I am currently trying_. Even when you don't think you're trying hard, you're at least going through the motions; that'll do for a baseline to improve on.

Comment: That's a different question ("*than* clause"), but I suppose it's safe to recast it however you please, because the OP is gone, possibly never to return. For my part, I say the answer *to the OP's question* is yes, because no such thing as a null base case for a comparative exists in language. Any language.

Comment: I'm around. It is not an urgent question though. I'm not an english expert, so I don't know how to abstract the question. I will try to understand answers that do.

Comment: No matter which way you slice the question, the answer is yes: harder, higher, etc. comparatives are meaningful in the absence of a physical comparison (where "the base case is null"). If you ask for more peas at dinner, that doesn't mean you've already had some peas; you can have more than none as easily as more than one. Same goes for jumping. Contextually, you might be misleading whoever you're talking to, but in the absence of context, jumping higher is higher jumping than not jumping.

Comment: @JEL Initially, I also had the same thought: the null case in this context is simply a kind of *zero*, not a true null, so the comparatives work. However, I don't think it's idiomatic to use *try harder* (specifically) when the person isn't trying at all. It would be more 'natural' to say something like "Put in some effort" or, if we want to retain *try*, "Start trying".

Comment: @Lawrence, I agree that the OP doesn't mean a true null, and that's pretty much the crux of interpreting the question properly. However, in terms of "idiom" or what's "natural", that certainly depends on context: it would be "idiomatic", but more to the point, natural, for a track coach to tell an athlete who was sitting around not attempting anything to "try harder". The absence of context is where the interpretation of the question must fail, rather than on the misapplication of 'null' to the base case.